# C# using index r in other functions

Tags: c#, datagridviewrow

I'm a C# beginner and like your input!

I have a datagridview and want to do some stuff with the selected rows.
I dont want to place all the tasks in one large function..... I'd like to split it up in seperate task-functions.
I'm using 'r' to have the index of the selected line. But how do I get that index 'r' to be used in the functions do_stuff1, do_stuff2,....?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

```cs
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        do_stuff1();
        do_stuff2();
        do_stuff3();
    }
}

private void do_stuff1()
{
    //do stuff1 with selected row r
}

...
```

All help kindly appreciated!

Comment: just pass `r` as parameter: declare function as `private void do_stuff1(DataGridViewRow r)` and then call as `do_stuff1(r);`

Comment: Agree with @Serg, though you might want to use a more meaningful name than `r` in your methods.

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for! 
@ZoharPeled I'll certainly keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [comment from @Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522305/c-sharp-using-index-r-in-other-functions/72942138#comment124661735_70522305) helped me out:

> just pass `r` as parameter: declare function as `private void do_stuff1(DataGridViewRow r)` and then call as `do_stuff1(r);`

Thanks to @Serg and @ZoharPeled